# nusoap error : HTTP Error: socket read of headers timed out

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, nusoap

i need a help

i have a problem in using nusoap for PHP when client want to access service in server

the error is :

```
HTTP Error: socket read of headers timed out
```

this is my XML can be accessed at `[http://sobath-market.com/index.wsdl.php?wsdl][1]`

can someone help me??

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi this error often occurs for a new user who using nusoap , as the default response time has been to 30 seconds. As of your request exceeds more than this execution time, you are getting this error, to fix this issue change the following code in "nusoap.php" in your nusoap library

```
socket_set_timeout( $this->fp, $response_timeout);

to

socket_set_timeout( $this->fp, 200);
```

i hope you got the expected solution from this.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of changing the "nusoap.php" file you can call the constructor passing the timeout as a parameter.

```
$client = new nusoap_client(
    /*endpoint*/ $url,
    /*wsdl*/ $type,
    /*proxyhost*/ false,
    /*proxyport*/ false,
    /*proxyusername*/ false,
    /*proxypassword*/ false,
    /*timeout*/ $timeout, //here you can define timeout
    /*response_timeout*/ $responseTimeout, //here is what you want to define
    /*portName*/ '');
```